# axios/fetch request is stuck in pending state when requested from react native app to .net 6.0 api

Tags: react-native, axios, ios-simulator, .net-6.0, mobile-application

**Problem statement:**

I developed an api using .net 6.0 in Mac. I'm able to debug the .net code from postman but the same request not working from axios request.

**Observation:**
axios request code looks good and I tested this code by replacing with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and worked as expected.

Solution or suggestion required if am I missing any configuration?
I'm new to Mac.

The request from axios is not successful from react-native app. The api is stuck in pending state. I'm using Xcode simulator

**Below is the axios request:**

```
try{
            const response =  await axios.get('https://localhost:5001/api/profile',
            {
                // method:'Get',
                headers:{
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8,application/json',
                'Response-Type':'application/json'
                }
                
            })
            .then((respose) => 
            {
                // console.log(respose)
                return response
                
                
            })
            // .catch(error => console.log(error.message))

        }catch(error){
            console.log(error.message)

        }
```

[screenshot of the request from DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIkDM.png)
I tried to create get request from Xcode iOS simulator, but the request is stuck in pending state. Same request I tested from postman and it worked after disabling ssl.

Comment: Issue got resolved. There is no problem with axios code to send the get request. The issue is https (https://localhost:5001) requests are not working in Mac but I tried with http://localhost:5000 it is working as expected.
Can anyone help me how to resolve https requests?